# Flags page is difficult to parse

Tags: discussion, design

So here's a quick screenshot of my flags page to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

[image: My flags page]

Let's take the first flag (off-topic) as an example. It belongs to the post listed above, but it's much closer in proximity to the post below. So my brain thinks that it might belong to that post, rather than the one above. For this reason, often as I'm scrolling through my flags I'll have to stop and think about which post belongs to which flag, rather than simply being able to know at a glance.

Does anyone else have this problem? Is this something which is ever likely to be redesigned?

N.B. I can see *why* this is the case, but I still think it should be designed better. The first line with the post title is on its own line so that it doesn't crowd out the date and poster on the second line. This second line is what causes the large amount of separation. I get that the horizontal lines are meant to delineate posts, but the fact is my brain just doesn't see it that way.

Comment: I've actually experienced the opposite problem. A form I submitted at my school separated the labels for the input fields with horizontal rules, and I mistakenly thought that all the labels were for the fields above them because, well... why would you separate them like that?

Comment: I'm always searching for the outcome of the flags. Turns out that the most important aspect is in the middle of the textblock =/...

Comment: The lines can be interpreted as seperating a header from content. A bit of spacing between the flags would not go amiss imo, or maybe the removal of the line, and putting a pale background behind each flag which would clearly group the information together.

Comment: Maybe if the flag info was indented under the question title? Questions without an accepted answer appear to be indented under the flag info for the previous question because the score background is white. (With the green you can tell it's actually flush left) Or maybe just an outline around the score if it isn't answered?

Comment: I'd shove the flag reason ("off topic -- Laura, 2 days ago, helpful") over to be right justified so it sits right under the "asked 2 days ago" text.

Comment: There's a bunch of other problems with the flags page, too, like the fact that comment flags look just like post flags *and don't even link to the flagged comment* but rather to the post it is/was on. Still, I agree that the confusing layout is one problem, and that just fixing that alone would be a big improvement.

Answer (score 3):

This looks simple, but it isn't that simple:

Using the following CSS rules:

```
.mod-flag{
     clear: none;
     padding-top:25px !important;
}
```

The view changes to what I'd like it to be (FF 58.0.1)

[image]

But custom mod flags, or declined flags, have substantially longer text:

[image]

This makes it more understandable to have the full width available for that *tag description* --- *helpful/declined + description* part.

Comment: That definitely makes it more readable. Perhaps for longer tag descriptions the layout could revert to the old one.

Comment: What would be the proper way to go about asking for a change like this?

Comment: @Lauraducky you could open up a new post on meta, tag it [meta-tag:feature-request], and explain what you'd like to see changed, and why this would be beneficial for the site and it's users. You can refer to this post in that post, of course.

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363718/8718143), thank you