# Make the flags page easier to read

Tags: feature-request, design

## The problem

Recently I posted [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362958/8718143) discussing this page and its problems. The main issue is that because of the spacing, it looks like flags are associated with the post title below them rather than the post above. To illustrate the problem, see the below screenshot of my flags page:

[image: My flags page]

This problem is particularly prevalent when scrolled halfway down the flags page.

## The proposed solution

User Erik Von Asmuth came up with a possible solution for this in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363069/8718143). With the CSS rules below:

```
.mod-flag{
     clear: none;
     padding-top:25px !important;
}
```

You get an output similar to this:

[image: Sample output]

## The caveat

One small caveat to mention is that this causes custom flags and duplicate flags, which have longer descriptions, to behave strangely, as seen below:

[image: Strange output]

In order to combat this, I propose that all "short" tags be able to display further up so that by their proximity it makes them easier to scan quickly. Longer tags can revert to the old way of displaying them.

## Further comments

There are other problems with the flags page, such as how it's difficult to scan through quickly (your eye is constantly moving from side to side as it scans the flag outcomes), but this seems like a reasonable first step without requiring a total redesign.

As always, comments and improvements are welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: I've never really found it difficult to read the flags page. But if it's really an issue people are facing, would it not be sufficient to just have odd/even css colouring, rather than redesigning the page?

Comment: @Rob That might work as well, this is just one of the many ways it could be solved

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Yeah, that was from the same person, as stated.

Comment: The main difference is that this is a [meta-tag:feature-request] discussing a specific solution, while the previous post was a general discussion